# JavaScript Serialize Array to JSON

Tags: javascript, vb.net, json, serialization

I have "Form Designer" web application, in which I need to post the controls of the new form to an ASP.Net page to insert to DB, each time I create form control. I push it into two dimensional array, when user click save, this array will be serialized and sent to Server Page using Ajax.

Array string After Serialization Looks Like :

```
[
    [
        {"id":"cont_menu_tb1"},
        {"name":"cont_menu_tb1"},
        {"zindex":"500"},
        {"top":"128"},
        {"left":"214"}

    ]
    ,
    [
        {"id":"cont_menu_tb2"},     
            {"name":"cont_menu_tb2"},
        {"zindex":"500"},
        {"top":"275"},
        {"left":"203"}
    ]
]
```

I used `JSON.stringify(objCF_JSON)` to serialize it. Now how to De-Serialize the Array Again using Newton in VB.Net into two dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a two dimensional array, it is a single dimension array with 2 objects.

```
List<SomeObject> objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeObject>>(json);
```

where SomeObject has the properties name, width, height

Comment: thanks Tony, my problem was in String Format , also in Newton DLL, the problem was in Datatypes of the class

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use another one function of JSON library to deserialize string to object - JSON.parse(stringedObj).